# Compare strings in java and remove the part of string where they are identical

Tags: java, algorithm

I have two strings with me:

```
s1="MICROSOFT"
s2="APPLESOFT"
```

I need to compare the strings and remove the duplicate part (always towards the end) from the second string. So I should get "MICROSOFT" and "APPLE" as output.

I have compared both the strings character by character.

```
               String s1 = "MICROSOFT";
               String s2 = "APPLESOFT";

               for(int j=0; j<s1.length(); j++)
               {
                   char c1 = s1.charAt(j);
                   char c2 = s2.charAt(j);

                   if(c1==c2)
                       System.out.println("Match found!!!");
                   else
                       System.out.println("No match found!");
               }
```

It should check the strings and if the two strings have same characters until the end of string, then I need to remove that redundant part, SOFT in this case, from the second string. But I can't think of how to proceed from here.

There can be more duplicates...but we have to remove only those which are continuously identical. if i have APPWWSOFT and APPLESOFT, i should get APPLE again in the second string since we got LE different than WW in between

Can you guys please help me out here?

Comment: could the duplicate part be anywhere in the string or is it always at the end? Eg might you want to remove "SOFT" from "MICSOFTRO" and "APPSOFTLE"?

Comment: also could there be more duplicates? like APPAPPLESOFT and APPMICROSOFT should remove APP and SOFT?  also, the duplicate can be only one character? or there's always more than 1?

Comment: this question shouldn't get so many upvotes, i think. @GauravOjha are you asking about 2nd string's diff from 1st string? if so, this question should get negative votes and closed.

Comment: @The Cat: its always in the end

Comment: @Th0rndike: yes there can be more duplicates...but we have to remove only those which are continuously identical. if i have APPWWSOFT and APPLESOFT, i should get APPLE again in the second string since we got LE different than WW in betwen.

Comment: @VincenzoSanchez: with all due respect Vincenzo, I dont think this is a problem of just subtraction. But again, I'm merely a beginner, may be you're right, but i dont see a way through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem after racking some brains off. Please feel free to correct/improve/refine my code. The code not only works for "MICROSOFT" and "APPLESOFT" inputs, but also for inputs like "APPWWSOFT" and "APPLESOFT" (i needed to remove the continuous duplicates from the end - SOFT in both the above inputs). I'm in the learning stage and I'll appreciate any valuable inputs.

```
public class test
    {           
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            String s1 = "MICROSOFT";
            String s2 = "APPLESOFT";

            int counter1=0;
            int counter2=0;

            String[] test = new String[100];
            test[0]="";

            for(int j=0; j<s1.length(); j++)
            {
                char c1 = s1.charAt(j);
                char c2 = s2.charAt(j);

                if(c1==c2)
                {
                    if(counter1==counter2)
                    {
                        //System.out.println("Match found!!!");
                        test[0]=test[0]+c2;
                        counter2++;
                        //System.out.println("Counter 2: "+counter2);
                    }
                    else
                        test[0]="";
                }
               else
               {
                   //System.out.print("No match found!");
                   //System.out.println("Counter 2: "+counter2);
                   counter2=counter1+1;
                   test[0]="";
               }

               counter1++;
               //System.out.println("Counter 1: "+counter1);
                           }

             System.out.println(test[0]);
             System.out.println(s2.replaceAll(test[0]," "));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Search and read about **Longest Common Subsequence**, you can find efficient algorithms to find out the LCS of two input strings. After finding the LCS of the input strings, it is easy to manipulate the inputs. For example, in your case an LCS algorithm will find "SOFT" as the LCS of these two strings, then you might check whether the LCS is in the final part of the 2nd input and then remove it easily. I hope this idea helps.

An example LCS code in Java is here, try it: http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/96optimization/LCS.java.html

Example scenario (pseudocode):

```
input1: "MISROSOFT";
input2: "APPLESOFT";

execute LCS(input1, input2);
store the result in lcs, now lcs = "SOFT";

iterate over the characters of input2,
if a character exists in lcs then remove it from input2.
```

Comment: He wants to remove any similar characters from the 2 strings. So, I don't think longest common  subsequence can be applied ... only if you apply it repeatedly ...

Comment: Check this out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2929557/java-longest-common-subsequence

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand, you want to remove any identical characters from the two strings. By identical I mean:  same position and same character(code). I think the following linear complexity solution is the simplest:

```
 StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
 StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder(); //if you want to remove the identical char 
                                          //only from one string you don't need the 2nd sb
 char c;
 for(int i = 0; i<Math.min(s1.length,s2.length);i++){
     if((c = s1.charAt(i)) != s2.charAt(i)){
           sb1.append(c);
     }
 }
 return sb1.toString();
```

Comment: Your code is the best I tried all the solutions in this post kudos

Answer (score 2):

Try this algo- Create characters sequences of your first string and find it in second string.

performance -
Average case  = (s1.length()-1)sq

```
public class SeqFind {
    public static String searchReplace(String s1,String s2) {
        String s3;
        boolean brk=false;
        for(int j=s1.length();j>0&&!brk;j--){
        for (int i = j-4; i > 0; i--) {
            String string = s1.substring( i,j);
            if(s2.contains(string)){
                System.out.println(s2+" - "+string+" "+s2.replace( string,""));
                brk=true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
        return s3;      
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1 = "MICROSOFT";
        String s2 = "APPLESOFT";
        String s3 = searchReplace(s1,s2);
    }
}
```

Out put -
APPLESOFT - SOFT - APPLE

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. If I understand right this algorithm is finding the first matched pattern between the two strings and removing it from the second string. Right? 
It's almost what I want, but i want the matched pattern to be seen from the end. So if i take two strings like "APPWWSOFT" and "APPLESOFT", I woud get "APPLESOFT - APP LESOFT" as the output now, however, i need "APPLESOFT - SOFT - APPLE" as the output.

Comment: code updated and this will start searching from end and atleast 4 word should be matched

Comment: Thanks a lot Quoi (Subhrajyoti)!! It works as a charm..but I have solved my problem myself and posted the solution below. Nothing gives you more pleasure than your own working code :)
Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
   public class Match {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String s1="MICROSOFT";
    String s2="APPLESOFT";
    String[] s=new String[10];
    String s3;
    int j=0,k=0;
    for(int i=s2.length();i>0;i--)
    {
        s[j]=s2.substring(k,s2.length());
        if(s1.contains(s[j]))
        {
            s3=s2.substring(0,j);
                                 System.out.println(s1+""+s3);

            System.exit(0);

        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("");
        }
                                j++;
                                k++;
    }


}

     }
```

I have edited the code you can give it an another try.

Comment: I have solved my problem Kanhai and posted the solution, but I'll check yours too and let you know if it works. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

try this, not tested thou

```
 String s1 = "MICROSOFT";
         String s2 = "APPLESOFT";
         String s3="";
         for(int j=0; j<s1.length(); j++)
         {
             if(s1.charAt(j)==s2.charAt(j)){
                 s3+=s1.charAt(j);
             }
         }
         System.out.println(s1.replace(s3, " ") + " \n"+ s2.replace(s3, " "));
```

Comment: I think you mean `!=` instead of `==` and you won't need the replace. Replace wouldn't work if the characters are not together.

Comment: @PeterLawrey i compare the chars and if they are equal then append it to s3. as i said not tested  :P

Comment: @Chaitanya.. If you are trying to append.. Then `StirngBuffer` would be a better choice.. (And rather than appending the matching character, you can append non-matching character.. Will save you from `replace` code.)

Comment: @RohitJain yes, performance wise. but i was only showin a sample :P

Comment: @chaitanya10.. I understand.. I just quoted when I thought it should be quoted.. :)

Comment: @chaitanya10: thanks for the help dude. But there can be more duplicates...but we have to remove only those which are continuously identical. if i have APPWWSOFT and APPLESOFT, i should get APPLE again in the second string since we got LE different than WW in between.

Answer (score 0):

You should rather use `StringBuffer` if you want your `String` to be modified..

And in this case, you can have one extra `StringBuffer`, in which you can keep on appending non-matching character: -

```
    StringBuffer s1 = new StringBuffer("MICROSOFT");
    StringBuffer s2 = new StringBuffer("APPLESOFT");
    StringBuffer s3 = new StringBuffer();

    for(int j=0; j<s1.length(); j++)
    {
        char c1 = s1.charAt(j);
        char c2 = s2.charAt(j);

        if(c1==c2) {
            System.out.println("Match found!!!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("No match found!");
            s3.append(c1);
        }
    }
    s1 = s3;
    System.out.println(s1);    // Prints "MICRO"
```

Comment: This code (as well as the OP's) will **NOT** find/remove anything in "MICROSOFT" and " APPLESOFT" pair

Comment: @GermannArlington.. This code is not removing anything from `MICROSOFT` or `APPLESOFT`.. But it is creating a new `StringBuffer` of non-matching character.. Which is later on assigned to the original `s3'.. It prints `MICRO` non-matching character which OP wants..

Comment: It will **NOT** print anything useful (matches) for **my** two given strings. Give that a try.

Comment: I'm sorry, but which `strings` you are talking about??.. OP didn't wanted the `Matching` string, he wanted to remove them.. So, I used this approach.. I would welcome your advice on any improvement over the code..

Comment: So, the OP wanted to **remove** ANY? substrings from the second string? They did **NOT** want to remove **matching** part of the strings? **Your** code will **NOT** find any match to remove in two string that I suggested in my first comment: "MICROSOFT" and " APPLESOFT". **Your** code will print "MICROSOFT" (full word with nothing removed) because you are doing positional match **ONLY** **AND** it will **blow up** when the s1 is longer than s2 as well. Do you need any more **constructive** advice?