# Given two sequences, find the length of longest subsequence present in both of them. Both the strings are of uppercase

Tags: java

Below is my java snippet. I am getting the wrong answer for this test case. Can anybody tell me what is wrong with my code
Input:
27 12

GEBEOCFUFTSXDIXTIGSIEEHKCHZ
DFLILRJQFNXZ

Its Correct output is:
4

And Your Code's output is:
5

```
class Solution{
    // function to find LCS
    static int lcs(int p, int q, String s1, String s2){
        int i =0;
        int j =0;
        int count=0;
        
        while(j<q)
        {
            int temp = i;
            while(temp < p)
            {
                if(s2.charAt(j) == s1.charAt(temp))
                {
                    count++;
                    i=temp+1;
                }
                temp++;
            }
              j++;
        }
        return count;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: For starters, your code counts a character in s2 multiple times if that character occurs more than one time in s1.

Comment: Btw, I think you should be using `Dynamic Programming` for this problem.

Comment: The logic looks wrong .. for starters you want to look for substrings from the shorter string in the larger string - or stop when you've reached the length of the shorter string - for obvious reasons.

Comment: Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2929557/java-longest-common-subsequence will give some ideas?

Comment: Which of these is in the first string? DFLI FLIL LILR ILRJ LRJQ RJQF JQFN QFNX FNXZ   What is your definition of largest matching sub-sequence??